# Deploying Ruby on Rails 6 - AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Docker: ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't seem to figure out a proper way to set **secret_key_base** for Ruby on Rails 6 - AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Docker deploy. Thus, the deploy keeps failing. I've been trying to follow this tutorial: https://dev.to/fdoxyz/elastic-beanstalk-apps-using-docker-containers-56l8

System:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
- Bundler version 2.1.4
- Rails 6.0.2.1
- Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
- Node v12.16.1

Here are the steps I take from empty dir to deploy:

```
mkdir new_project && cd new_project
eb init
     2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
     2) [ Create new Application ]
     (default is "new_project")
     8) Docker
     Do you want to set up SSH for your instances? Y
     Select a keypair.

eb create
     Enter Environment Name (default is new-project-dev)
     Enter DNS CNAME prefix (default is new-project-dev)
     Select a load balancer type: 2) application
     enable Spot Fleet? n
     download the sample application into the current directory? n

eb setenv SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(ruby -e "require 'securerandom';puts SecureRandom.hex(64)")
eb setenv RAILS_ENV=production

cat .gitignore
rails new .
vim .gitignore (paste old contents of gitignore)
touch Dockerfile
vim Dockerfile

===============
FROM ruby:2.6.5

# Install NodeJS & Yarn
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install apt-transport-https && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && \
    apt-get purge nodejs && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install nodejs -y && \
    npm install yarn -g  && \
    gem install bundler -v 2.1.4

# Workdir and add dependencies
WORKDIR /app/
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/

# Throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

# Install dependencies
ARG RAILS_MASTER_KEY
ENV RAILS_ENV=production NODE_ENV=production RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1
RUN bundle install --without development test

# Add the app code, precompile assets and use non-root user
ADD . /app/
RUN rake assets:precompile DISABLE_SPRING=1 && \
    chown -R nobody:nogroup /app
USER nobody
ENV HOME /app

# Make sure to explicitly bind to port & interface
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0"]
===============

vim config/environments/production.rb
insert at the top of the file:
    config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]

git add . && git commit -m "Initial commit"
eb use new_project-dev
eb deploy
```

Here's a full log from ssh-ing to the instance at '/var/log/eb-activity.log':

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maxtocarev/eb-log/master/eb-activity.log

Answer (score 0):

The `secret_key_base` is a value stored in [Rails encrypted credentials](https://blog.engineyard.com/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2). Looks like the command `rake assets:precompile` from inside the Dockerfile fails when building the Docker image because it needs the `secret_key_base` value. I believe this happens because it doesn't have the `config/master.key` in your local project. I would recommend passing it to `docker build` using something like this:

```
docker build  --build-arg RAILS_MASTER_KEY=${RAILS_MASTER_KEY} ...
```

I definitely don't recommended including `config/master.key` inside the project itself because of security reasons, that's why I would use the ENV variable instead.

In this case looks like you're using the Elastic Beanstalk "auto build" (which means the Docker image is built on each deploy from your source code), so you're not building the image manually. This could be fixed by adding the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env variable using `eb setenv RAILS_MASTER_KEY=XXXXXXXX` or from the AWS web console.

Comment: Thanks Fernando! Do you use `Dockerrun.aws.json`? I only have `Dockerfile` in my root dir. Where do I actually include `docker build` command?

Comment: I use `Dockerrun.aws.json`, it works for single and multi container setups. Mutli-container is cool bc you can eventually deploy a separate Sidekiq container in your deployment. There's an issue though, if you have the `Dockerfile` in your root Dir I believe AWS will not take `Dockerrun.aws.json` into consideration (it needs to be somewhere else in your project). I did a Google search and couldn't find how to pass in the argument. I would maybe recommend building and pushing your container image manually to ECR (try CI/CD) using `Dockerrun.aws.json` (the dev.to tutorial has links to docs)